# Perl: Shebang (space?) "#! "?

Tags: unix, sh

I've seen both:

```
#!/path/...
#! /path/...
```

What's right? Does it matter? Is there a history?

I've heard that an ancient version of Unix required there not be a space.  But then I heard that was just a rumor.  Does anyone know for certain?

---

***Edit:** I couldn't think where better to ask this.  It is programming related, since the space could make the program operate in a different way, for all I know.  Thus I asked it here.*

Comment: If you've seen both and both work, it would stand to reason that it's a matter of preference/aesthetic.

Comment: I'm not sure how this _doesn't_ relate to programming.

Comment: @JustinPearce: That's not a safe assumption; it's possible that some systems don't permit a space after the `#!`, which would make the version with no space more portable.  But as it turns out, it's likely that all systems do permit blanks; see my answer for details.

Comment: @ergosys, Yes, it's technically only related to the kernel (not programming), but part of programming is getting the kernel to run your program. I don't mind having this question here, and the expertise to answer the question is here. (How can one vote not to close?)

Comment: @ikegami, I disagree, it's related to writing scripts, which is programming.

Comment: This ought to be moved to [Unix SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com).  Unfortunately, that's not one of the choices in the vote-to-close box.

Comment: @ergosys, It's not used by scripting languages, so it no more related to writing scripts than a question about `cp`'s usage. (Well, `perl` does parse it to support systems that don't support `#!`. e.g. Pass a file with `#!/usr/bin/python` to `perl` and it will launch `python`. e.g. Pass a file with `#!/usr/bin/perl -w` to `perl`, and it will turn on warnings even if the `#!` line wasn't used to launch the script. Perl doesn't care if there's white space after the `#!` or not.)

Comment: @ikegami: As far as I know, you can't vote to close; you can only vote to re-open after a question has been closed.

Comment: @ikegami, I will refrain from ranting about the counter-productivity of siloing up programming knowledge among SO's sister sites, and the necessary hair splitting required to do so.

Comment: Not to say that we'll ever digress, but it would be nice to know if someone wants to build a new kernel from something a little more ancient.  My knowledge of unix/linux has faded over time and I'm sure it never compared to some of yours.

Comment: @ergosys, Good, cause I said I wanted to vote *against* closing the question.

Comment: @ikegami, directed more at those that decided to silo things up, then those that have to split the hairs to figure out where things go.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I also have a vague memory that whitespace was not allowed in some old Unix-like systems, but a bit of research doesn't support that.

According to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29), the `#!` syntax was introduced in Version 8 Unix in January, 1980.  Dennis Ritchie's initial announcement of this feature says:

> The system has been changed so that if a file being executed begins
>   with the magic characters `#!`, the rest of the line is understood to
>   be the name of an interpreter for the executed file. Previously (and
>   in fact still) the shell did much of this job; it automatically
>   executed itself on a text file with executable mode when the text
>   file's name was typed as a command. Putting the facility into the
>   system gives the following benefits.

[SNIP]

> To take advantage of this wonderful opportunity, put
>
> ```
> #! /bin/sh
> ```
>
> at the left margin of the first line of your shell scripts. Blanks
>   after `!` are OK.  Use a complete pathname (no search is done). At the
>   moment the whole line is restricted to 16 characters but this limit
>   will be raised.

It's conceivable that some later Unix-like system supported the `#!` syntax but didn't allow blanks after the `!`, but given that the very first implementation explicitly allowed blanks, that seems unlikely.

leonbloy's answer provides some more context.

**UPDATE :**

The Perl interpreter itself recognizes a line starting with `#!`, even on systems where that's not recognized by the kernel.  Run `perldoc perlrun` or see [this web page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for details.

> The #! line is always examined for switches as the line is being
>   parsed. Thus, if you're on a machine that allows only one argument
>   with the #! line, or worse, doesn't even recognize the #! line, you
>   still can get consistent switch behaviour regardless of how Perl was
>   invoked, even if -x was used to find the beginning of the program.

Perl also permits whitespace after the `#!`.

(Personally, I prefer to write the `#!` line without whitespace, but it will work either way.)

And [leonjoy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10197925/827263) points to [this web page by Sven Mascheck](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/), which discusses the history of #! in depth. (I mention this now because of a recent discussion on comp.unix.shell.)

Comment: Thanks for the opportunity to broaden my understanding, Keith. My shell-fu is not quite as good as it could be so my assumption was made with my limited experience. Learn something new every day. :D

Answer (score 10):

It seems to usually work both ways. [See here](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#blankrequired). I'd say that the no-space version is much more common today, and, to me, much more appealing.

BTW, this is not specifically related to Perl (but it's definitely related to programming).

Comment: That link is so amazingly researched that a +1 rubs off on you :)