# "bad variable name" in bash script started by cron

Tags: bash, cron

Works just fine when running it manually on the shell but when I setup a cronjob to run it on reboot I get "bad variable name".

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/duplicityCleanUp
export PASSPHRASE=foo
duplicity remove-older-than 30D --force --gio smb://remote/archiv/
duplicity remove-all-but-n-full 1 --force --gio smb://remote/archiv/
unset PASSPHRASE
```

Comment: `#! /bin/sh` has a wrong space. It should be `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: @fedorqui I thought the space was wrong too, but apparently it is acceptable... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197690/perl-shebang-space

Comment: @MarkSetchell interesting! I learn things every day in this site. Very good to know.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is a space between the `#!` and the `/bin/sh`.  I don't think this is the reported problem but it needs fixing *

I guess that you are using a version of Unix or Linux where `/bin/sh` is not bash so the
export syntax is wrong.

Alter your script to say

```
PASSPHRASE=foo
export PASSPHRASE
```

See this answer [UNIX export command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328223/unix-export-command)

* *it's not a problem, see comments*

Comment: you may check with: "ls -lrt /bin/sh" to see whether it is really pointing to bash

Comment: [The space is fine actually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10197690/4518341), no problem there.

Comment: it works for me on some pipelines of deployments actions

Answer (score 4):

They way you export or set your variables are incompatible with your shell. When executing the script - try and use different shell.

```
sh yourscript.sh 
bash yourscript.sh 
ksh yourscript.sh
csh yourscript.sh
zsh yourscript.sh
```

Mostly bash will work for you.