# Bad variable name in Bash from a Git alias

Tags: git, bash, git-alias

I have the following Git alias in my global git config.

```
pushnew = !f() { export tmp_branch=`git branch | grep '* ' | tr -d '* '` && git push --set-upstream origin $tmp_branch; unset $tmp_branch; }; f
```

When running it I get the following output:

```
 * [new branch]      bug/graphs -> bug/graphs
Branch bug/graphs set up to track remote branch bug/graphs from origin.
f() { export tmp_branch=`git branch | grep '* ' | tr -d '* '` && git push --set-upstream origin $tmp_branch; unset $tmp_branch; }; f: 1: unset: bug/graphs: bad variable name
```

I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26251272/bad-variable-name-in-bash-script-started-by-cron) but if that is the solution then how do I apply the fix within the context of a Git alias?

Comment: I guess it won't be too problematic in this context but you should always quote your shell variables, e.g. `git push --set-upstream origin "$tmp_branch"`. This prevents word splitting, when there are spaces inside the variable's value and glob expansion, when there are characters such as `*`.

Comment: If you want to find out the current branch name you do not want to be `grep`ping the output from `git branch`. You want to use `git symbolic-ref HEAD` (possibly with the `--short` argument as well). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593051/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-current-checked-out-git-branch .

Comment: Tom, Etan: thanks for those suggestions - will definitely improve it and help with future maintenance

Comment: There's no real need to unset `tmp_branch`, since it is defined in the subshell created by Git to evaluate the alias. There's also no need to export it; you are only expanding it in the same shell where it is defined, not a child process. `f() { git push --set-upstream origin "$(git symbolic-ref HEAD)"; }` should suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
unset tmp_branch
```

If you try unset `$tmp_branch`, the shell will substitute the value of `$tmp_branch`, trying to unset `bug/graphs`.